# How to set HTML5 required attribute in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to mark a `text` input box as **required** in Javascript.

```
<input id="edName" type="text" id="name">
```

If the field is initially marked as `required`:

```
<form>
    <input id="edName" type="text" id="name" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

when the user tries to submit they are given a validation error:

[image]

But now I want to set the `required` attribute at *"runtime"*, through Javascript:

```
<form>
    <input id="edName" type="text" id="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

with the corresponding script:

```
//recommended W3C HTML5 syntax for boolean attributes
document.getElementById("edName").attributes["required"] = "";
```

Except when I submit now, there is no validation check, no block.

What is the *correct* way to set an *HTML5 validation boolean attribute*?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CP7sR/3/)

## What's the value of the attribute, you ask?

The HTML5 validation [`required` attribute is documented](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) as a `Boolean`:

> ### **4.10.7.3.4 The [`required`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-required) attribute**
>
> The **`required`** attribute is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute). When specified, the element is required.

There is a lot of hand-wringing about how to define a `boolean` attribute. The HTML5 spec notes:

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

This means that you can specify a `required` **boolean** attribute two different ways:

```
edName.attributes.required = ""; //the empty string
edName.attributes.required = "required"; //the attribute's canonical name
```

## But what is the value of the attribute *really*?

When you look at [my jsFiddle of this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/CP7sR/3/), you'll notice that if the `required` attribute is defined in the markup:

```
<input id="edName" type="text" id="name" required>
```

Then the attribute's value is ***not*** the empty string, nor the canonical name of the attribute:

```
edName.attributes.required = [object Attr]
```

That might lead to a solution.

Comment: I do not understand why they do not allow `required="false"`, did they ever write a template before writing the standard ? Conditional attributes are usually a pain, it is way easier to just put that boolean in the attribute value...

Comment: Is it possible manually show that text over required input: "Please fill this out this field."?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Agreed. People who write standards (HTML, CSS and even JS) are completely twisted minds. Those languages are a complete mess, but too widely used to be easily replaced, unfortunately...

Answer (score 160, accepted):

## Short version

```
element.setAttribute("required", "");    //turns required on
element.required = true;                 //turns required on through reflected attribute
jQuery(element).attr('required', '');    //turns required on
$("#elementId").attr('required', '');    //turns required on

element.removeAttribute("required");     //turns required off
element.required = false;                //turns required off through reflected attribute
jQuery(element).removeAttr('required');  //turns required off
$("#elementId").removeAttr('required');  //turns required off

if (edName.hasAttribute("required")) { }  //check if required
if (edName.required) { }                 //check if required using reflected attribute
```

## Long Version

Once T.J. Crowder managed to point out [reflected properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-required), i learned that following syntax is **wrong**:

```
element.attributes["name"] = value; //bad! Overwrites the HtmlAttribute object
element.attributes.name = value;    //bad! Overwrites the HtmlAttribute object
value = element.attributes.name;    //bad! Returns the HtmlAttribute object, not its value
value = element.attributes["name"]; //bad! Returns the HtmlAttribute object, not its value
```

You ***must*** go through `element.getAttribute` and `element.setAttribute`:

```
element.getAttribute("foo");         //correct
element.setAttribute("foo", "test"); //correct
```

This is because the attribute actually contains a special **HtmlAttribute** object:

```
element.attributes["foo"];           //returns HtmlAttribute object, not the value of the attribute
element.attributes.foo;              //returns HtmlAttribute object, not the value of the attribute
```

By setting an attribute value to "true", you are mistakenly setting it to a **String** object, rather than the **HtmlAttribute** object it requires:

```
element.attributes["foo"] = "true";  //error because "true" is not a HtmlAttribute object
element.setAttribute("foo", "true"); //error because "true" is not an HtmlAttribute object
```

Conceptually the correct idea (expressed in a typed language), is:

```
HtmlAttribute attribute = new HtmlAttribute();
attribute.value = "";
element.attributes["required"] = attribute;
```

This is why:

- `getAttribute(name)`
- `setAttribute(name, value)`

exist. They do the work on assigning the value to the HtmlAttribute object inside.

On top of this, some attribute are **reflected**. This means that you can access them more nicely from Javascript:

```
//Set the required attribute
//element.setAttribute("required", ""); 
element.required = true;

//Check the attribute
//if (element.getAttribute("required")) {...}
if (element.required) {...}

//Remove the required attribute
//element.removeAttribute("required");
element.required = false;
```

What you **don't** want to do is mistakenly use the `.attributes` collection:

```
element.attributes.required = true;     //WRONG!
if (element.attributes.required) {...}  //WRONG!
element.attributes.required = false;    //WRONG!
```

## Testing Cases

This led to testing around the use of a `required` attribute, comparing the values returned through the attribute, and the reflected property

```
document.getElementById("name").required;
document.getElementById("name").getAttribute("required");
```

with results:

```
HTML                         .required        .getAttribute("required")
==========================   ===============  =========================
<input>                      false (Boolean)  null (Object)
<input required>             true  (Boolean)  "" (String)
<input required="">          true  (Boolean)  "" (String)
<input required="required">  true  (Boolean)  "required" (String)
<input required="true">      true  (Boolean)  "true" (String)
<input required="false">     true  (Boolean)  "false" (String)
<input required="0">         true  (Boolean)  "0" (String)
```

Trying to access the `.attributes` collection directly is wrong. It returns the object that represents the DOM attribute:

```
edName.attributes["required"] => [object Attr]
edName.attributes.required    => [object Attr]
```

This explains why you should never talk to the `.attributes` collect directly. You're not manipulating the *values* of the attributes, but the objects that represent the attributes themselves.

## How to set required?

What's the correct way to set `required` on an attribute? You have two choices, either the reflected *property*, or through correctly setting the attribute:

```
element.setAttribute("required", "");         //Correct
element.required = true;                      //Correct
```

Strictly speaking, any other value will "set" the attribute. But the definition of `Boolean` attributes dictate that it should only be set to the empty string `""` to indicate *true*. The following methods all work to **set** the `required` **Boolean** attribute,

but **do not use** them:

```
element.setAttribute("required", "required"); //valid, but not preferred
element.setAttribute("required", "foo");      //works, but silly
element.setAttribute("required", "true");     //Works, but don't do it, because:
element.setAttribute("required", "false");    //also sets required boolean to true
element.setAttribute("required", false);      //also sets required boolean to true
element.setAttribute("required", 0);          //also sets required boolean to true
```

We already learned that trying to set the attribute directly is wrong:

```
edName.attributes["required"] = true;       //wrong
edName.attributes["required"] = "";         //wrong
edName.attributes["required"] = "required"; //wrong
edName.attributes.required = true;          //wrong
edName.attributes.required = "";            //wrong
edName.attributes.required = "required";    //wrong
```

## How to **clear** required?

The trick when trying to *remove* the `required` attribute is that it's easy to accidentally turn it on:

```
edName.removeAttribute("required");     //Correct
edName.required = false;                //Correct
```

With the invalid ways:

```
edName.setAttribute("required", null);    //WRONG! Actually turns required on!
edName.setAttribute("required", "");      //WRONG! Actually turns required on!
edName.setAttribute("required", "false"); //WRONG! Actually turns required on!
edName.setAttribute("required", false);   //WRONG! Actually turns required on!
edName.setAttribute("required", 0);       //WRONG! Actually turns required on!
```

When using the reflected `.required` property, you can also use any *"falsey"* values to turn it off, and truthy values to turn it on. But just stick to true and false for clarity.

## How to *check* for `required`?

Check for the presence of the attribute through the `.hasAttribute("required")` method:

```
if (edName.hasAttribute("required"))
{
}
```

You can also check it through the  **Boolean** reflected `.required` property:

```
if (edName.required)
{
}
```

Comment: What is the distinction between the variables `element` and `edName`?

Comment: One is where i forgot to convert specific element name `edName` (i.e. Name Input Box) into the generic `element`.

Comment: *"You **must** go through `element.getAttribute` and `element.setAttribute`:"* Just for clarity, you can use the `attributes` `NamedNodeMap` to change an attribute's value if you know the attribute is already there, you just can't use it to add an attribute that isn't there (or to remove one that is). So that approach isn't useful for boolean attributes like `required` because what matters with them is whether they're there, not what their value is. But yes, reflected properties are usually easier. :-)

Answer (score 167):

`required` is a [reflected property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-required) (like `id`, `name`, `type`, and such), so:

```
element.required = true;
```

...where `element` is the actual `input` DOM element, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("edName").required = true;
```

---

(Just for completeness.)

Re:

> Then the attribute's value is not the empty string, nor the canonical name of the attribute:
>
> ```
> edName.attributes.required = [object Attr]
> ```

That's because `required` in that code is an *attribute object*, not a string; `attributes` is a [`NamedNodeMap`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) whose values are [`Attr` objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-attr). To get the value of one of them, you'd look at its `value` property. But for a boolean attribute, the value isn't relevant; the attribute is either present in the map (true) or not present (false).

So if `required` *weren't* reflected, you'd set it by adding the attribute:

```
element.setAttribute("required", "");
```

...which is the equivalent of `element.required = true`. You'd clear it by removing it entirely:

```
element.removeAttribute("required");
```

...which is the equivalent of `element.required = false`.

But we don't have to do that with `required`, since it's reflected.

Answer (score 14):

What matters isn't the attribute but the *property*, and its value is a boolean.

You can set it using

```
 document.getElementById("edName").required = true;
```

Answer (score 10):

And the jquery version:

```
$('input').attr('required', true)
$('input').attr('required', false)
```

I know it's beyond the question, but maybe someone will find this helpful :)

Comment: actually, use `prop()` instead of `attr()` :)

Comment: @PierreDuc It's 2019 .. we don't use :) any more

Comment: @a20 last time I checked, I am still using it. So, I guess you are wrong

Comment: I was kidding my brother .. sorry!

Answer (score 3):

```
let formelems = document.querySelectorAll('input,textarea,select');
formelems.forEach((formelem) => {
  formelem.required = true;

});
```

If you wish to make all input, textarea, and select elements required.

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
document.getElementById("edName").required = true;
```