# How to remove an attribute from a DOM element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to use javascript to remove an attribute from a DOM node:

```
<div id="foo">Hi there</div>
```

First i add an attribute:

```
document.getElementById("foo").attributes['contoso'] = "Hello, world!";
```

Then i remove it:

```
document.getElementById("foo").removeAttribute("contoso");
```

Except the attribute is still there.

So then i try to *really* remove it:

```
document.getElementById("foo").attributes['contoso'] = null;
```

And now it's `null`, which is different than when it started, which was `undefined`.

What is the correct way to remove an attribute from an element?

[jsFiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/7su7C/)

**Note**: Replace the attribute `contoso`, with the attribute `required`, and you'll understand what [i'm *trying* to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript)

## State table

```
                       foo.attributes.contoso  foo.hasAttribute("contoso")
                       ======================  ===========================
Before setting         undefined               false
After setting          Hello, world!           false
After removing         Hello, world!           false
After really removing  null                    false
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7su7C/1/

Comment: @cske (and others who think it's a duplicate), don't confuse removing a `property` from a **Javascript** object, with removing an `attribute` from a **DOM** object. If this were a javascript object it would have worked.

Comment: delete works(but cleaner to use set/get methods) looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, ... you are accessing DOM objects (browser internal) attributes with a javascript interface

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't use the `attributes` collection to work with attributes. Instead use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) and [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute):

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");

foo.hasAttribute('contoso'); // false
foo.getAttribute('contoso'); // null

foo.setAttribute('contoso', 'Hello, world!');

foo.hasAttribute('contoso'); // true
foo.getAttribute('contoso'); // 'Hello, world!'

foo.removeAttribute('contoso');

foo.hasAttribute('contoso'); // false
foo.getAttribute('contoso'); // null, 

// It has been removed properly, trying to set it to undefined will end up
// setting it to the string "undefined"
```

Comment: Is there guidance somewhere that accessing a DOM object's `.attributes` collection is to be avoided? If so, then i have a world of code to re-think.

Comment: @IanBoyd I'm not sure of any particular reference material. I've never worked directly with it. I know that there are some inconsistencies though. In `IE8` when you iterate through it you get all possible attributes whereas in `IE9` you only get the ones that have been defined. It also seems to be incompatible with `removeAttribute` judging from the behaviour you describe in your question.

Comment: @Paulpro, Why do you use `foo.hasAttribute('x')` instead of `foo.x === undefined`?

Comment: `foo.x` is a property, not an attribute, and might not have the same value as `foo.get attribute( 'x' )`