# Unhide hidden objects from a website

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a javascript code that can unhide (reveal)  some unhidden objects of a website.

Let me explain you more deeply.
There is one box with some items inside.
Lets say all the items that are being load to this box are 2000 but the website hide the 800.
Could i do something to reveal them?

The code that the website use (as i can see in the "inspect element" of chrome) is the following

```
 <div class="_3hqu" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532">
 <table class="_2x_v uiGrid _51mz" cols="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0">
 <tbody data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0">
 <tr class="_51mx" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2">
 <td class="_51m- vMid" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$image">
 <div class="_4b2j" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$image.0">
 <img class="_2x_w img" src=" IMAGE LINK" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$image.0.0">
 </div>
 </td>
<td class="_2x_x _51m- vMid" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$text">
<div class="_2x_y" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$text.0">NAME</div>
<div class="_2x_z" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$text.1"></div>
<div class="_2x_z" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$text.2"></div>
</td>
<td class="_51mw _51m- vMid" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$widget">
<a aria-checked="true" aria-labelledby="100000533954532-name" aria-describedby="100000533954532-subtitle" class="_3hqy _3hqz" href="#" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" data-reactid=".ih.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1:$100000533954532.0.0.$2.$widget.0">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

So this is the code for only one element.
the `$100000533954532` is the value of this element (without the $ )

and after 1200 of this elements with same code but different values
there is this code that "hides" the other 800 elements.

```
<input type="hidden" name="at_limit" value="false" data-reactid=".ih.1">
<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="1326941442" data-reactid=".ih.2">
<input type="hidden" name="profileChooserItems" value="{ "000001":1, "000002":1, etc...
 data-reactid=".ih.3">
```

Is it possible with javascript code to reveal the hidden values (elements) of this table???

Comment: Do you want to convert the inputs, type equals hidden, to divs and tables?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles exactly! so they can appear at the table as elements!

Comment: So how do the inputs (type hidden) map to the example div/table you provided? In other words, in the div/table, what is fixed, and what is variable, and where in the inputs do the variables get their values?

Comment: You see on the hidden code in the last line there are some values (000001,000002 etc.) i want these values to appear to the table as in the example... to replace the values of the example in some words

Answer (score 0):

what you need is remove property from collection of DOM elements
try this:

`document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"]').removeAttribute("type");`

[Example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sy7q7tuk/)

[Similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770925/how-to-remove-an-attribute-from-a-dom-element-using-javascript)

Comment: when i paste your code in the console of chrome it says "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of grabbing an `input` element and using the attributes and values contained therein to dynamically create a more complex set of HTML nodes:

[JSFiddle it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/0033zuaa/)

```
<input type="hidden" name="at_limit" value="false" data-reactid=".ih.1">

<script>

var at_limit = document.querySelector('input[name="at_limit"]');
var reactid = at_limit.getAttribute('data-reactid');
var toggle = (at_limit.value === "true");

var div  = document.createElement("DIV");
var tbl  = document.createElement("TABLE");
var tbdy = document.createElement("TBODY");
var tr   = document.createElement("TR");
var td   = document.createElement("TD");
var anc  = document.createElement("A");
anc.href = "page.html?reactid=" + reactid;
anc.className = ( toggle )? 'yes': 'no';
var txt  = document.createTextNode(reactid);
anc.appendChild(txt);
td.appendChild(anc);
tr.appendChild(td);
tbdy.appendChild(tr);
tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
div.appendChild(tbl);
document.body.appendChild(div);

</script>

<style>
.no   { color: red; }
.yes  { color: green; }
table { border: solid blue 1px; }
</style>
```

That's the concept, now it's a matter of mapping the input elements to the targeted div/table structure.

Comment: this example is creating a new div etc? cant it be on the existing div table etc?

Comment: forget about last comment i didnt read on the last line thanks a lot. i will try this week your code and i will be back to accept your answer