# Remove HTML 5 validation from all elements

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to remove any HTML 5 validation on all `input` elements. Preferably using pure javascript.

Thinking it would be nice to create a file that can be included when developing, which would bring certain functionallity. Such as removing all required attributes, dumping post data, error reporting on/off, etc.

I have some jquery to remove the attribute from certain elements:

`$('div').removeAttr('required');​​​​​`

But would like to see something that works without jquery and applys to all elements that support html5 validation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an attribute from a DOM element using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770925/how-to-remove-an-attribute-from-a-dom-element-using-javascript)

Comment: Have you tried using `novalidate` attribute on your form?

Comment: [Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3094185/1064325)

Comment: @TadeášPeták thanks that would work great, however I envisige building a toolbar that allows me to disable/enable this withouth having to alter the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript function that removes the specified attribute of all existing elements:

```
function removeAttribute(attribute) {

    var allDocuments = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (var i=0; i < allDocuments.length; i++) {
        allDocuments[i].removeAttribute(attribute);
    }

}
```

To use this, simply call:

```
removeAttribute('required')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[required]').forEach(function(value,index){
  value.removeAttribute('required');
})
```

Comment: By the way my version will should be a lot more efficient :)