# Javascript set data-required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the `data-required` attribute according to data,if `value == 1` I want to set the `data-required` attribute to `true` else `false` .

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" id="txtPhone" name="phone" data-required="true" class="form-control">
```

**Javascript:**

```
 var value = $("#txtPhone").val();
        if (value == "1") {
            $("#txtPhone").... // Set data required true for txtphone input
        }
        else {
            $("#txtPhone")... // Set data required false for txtphone input
        }
```

How can I set `data-required` to true or false?

How can i do this by JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by "data-required"? required attribute or what?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want, but this might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: Still not very clear.

Comment: Edited the question, so as to clear what OP is asking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as i understand your question.. is this what you are looking for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/U49a7/)?

```
        var myvalue = $("#txtPhone").val();
        if (myvalue == "1") {
             $("#txtPhone").attr("data-required","true");
            alert(myvalue);
        }
        else {
           $("#txtPhone").attr("data-required","false");
            alert(myvalue);
        }
```

Comment: welcome user3722851 :)

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way :

```
var value = $("#txtPhone").val();
if (value == "1") {
    document.getElementById('txtPhone').setAttribute("data-required","true");
}
else {
    document.getElementById('txtPhone').setAttribute("data-required","false");
}
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75HwT/1/).

Comment: it doesn't work.. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/75HwT/)