# Using the required attribute on a password input

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, passwords

I'm trying to set a password input as required in JavaScript.

I have learnt from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript) post how to do it but it doesn't seem to work with my password input.

```html
<div class = "login">
<input type = "password" class = "enterPassword">
<button class = "submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

```js
var p = document.querySelector(".enterPassword");
p.required = true;
p.style.backgroundColor = "gray";

var s = document.querySelector(".submit");
s.addEventListener("click", clickHandler.bind(p));

function clickHandler() {
    console.log("Password: " + this.value);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80351/h4yszzzr/)

Although I do,

```
var p = document.querySelector(".enterPassword");
p.required = true;
```

as you can see, there is no required popup when a user fails to enter a password. Does anyone know why not?

Comment: Your submit button isn't a real submit button. It's just a regular button.

Comment: @4castle Does user2181397's answer below make it into a 'real' submit button?

Comment: Yes, it does. Because now they have a relationship through the form. Otherwise the button has no idea that it's supposed to validate the other input. A `div` has no semantic meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the elements in a form

```
<form>
<input type = "password" class = "enterPassword">
<button class = "submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can also check it without using `form`

```
document.querySelector(".enterPassword").validity.valid
```

this will return a Boolean value , but you wont see the error pop up

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/h4yszzzr/2/)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you wrap the whole thing in a div? Would it be possible to do without the div and instead make form the outer element with this attribute: `<form class = "login">` ? @user2181397

Comment: Yes it can be done. There is no need of _<div class = "login">_ you can ssign the same on _form_. I just reused your dom

Comment: When I click my button, the webpage sometimes refreshes. How can I stop this from happening? @user2181397