# How to remove or change an attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I want to remove and add `required` attribute to a field according to some conditions using jQuery. *This changes in DOM, but it doesn't change visually.*

### My code

```
$('#id').removeAttr('required');
$("#id").attr('ng-required','true');
$("#id").attr('required','true');
```

Even `used .prop()`,
but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: do you try `attr.$observe('required', ...)` in your directive?

Comment: @plong0,No I haven't used that.Can you please explain me how to use it.I have no idea how to use this cause I'm new to development.Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set HTML5 required attribute in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: No @rajeeshmenoth .My issue is it is not changing visually

Comment: What is controlling the visual aspect of the element (is it in an angular directive, plain html)?  What changes are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id').removeAttr('required');
```

Should be working, are you sure you are targeting the proper element?

Also the .prop should be used with 'false' not true

Answer (score 0):

Try this for adding and removing `required` attribute. Value of `required` attribute is `required` not `true`

```
$('#email').removeAttr('required');
$("#email").attr('required','required');
$("#email").attr('ng-required','required');
```

Comment: I have tried this also.I did change the DOM.But still it didn't change it visually.In browser it is still in previous state

Comment: <input name="email" id="email" ng-model="customer.email" type="email" class="ux-input" placeholder="Email" maxlength="30" >

Comment: ID of your element is `email` not `id` you are targeting wrong id.Updated the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry Leopard.I used that correctly.But have changed it to ask my question.I have used #email in Jquery

Comment: No @Leopard  there is no error.It also changes from DOM.But not visually from browser

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **'true'** use **true**

Try this code :

```
$('#id').removeAttr('required');
$('#id').prop('required',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using your jQuery like this:

```
$("#id").attr("required", false);
```