# JQuery .removeAttr('required') not working for input radio group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

What I am trying to do is when `$('input:radio[name="NeverWornRespbefore"]')` is selected, I want to remove the required attribute from the radio group `$('input:radio[name="eyeIrritation"]')`.

**My question**: How come the `.removeAttr('required')` or any other of the commented sections in the code won't remove the required tag? How do i get this to work?

*Thank you.*

```
<script>
//If user presses number 8 these radios don't have to be required
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('input:radio[name="NeverWornRespbefore"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Yes Never Worn one before') {

            console.log("triggered");
            //$('input:radio[name="eyeIrritation"]').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
            //$('.eyeIrritation').each().attr("required", "false");
            $('.eyeIrritation').removeAttr('required');
            console.log($('input#eyeIrritation'));
        }
    });

});
```

HERE is my cshtml:

```
<tr>
                    <td><label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 control-label" for="employeeName">8. If you've used a respirator, have you ever had any of the following problems? </label><be><label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 control-label" for="employeeName">(If you've never used a respirator, check the following checkbox @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.NeverWornRespbefore, "Yes Never Worn one before", new { Value = "Yes Never Worn one before" }) and go to question 9)</label></td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>No</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 control-label" for="employeeName">a. eye irritation:</label></td>
                    <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.eyeIrritation, "Yes", new {  Value = "YES" , required = "true"})</td>
                    <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.eyeIrritation, "No", new { Value = "NO"  , required = "true"})</td>
                </tr>
```

**HERE IS MY COMPLETED CODE With ANSWER found from COMMENTS**

```
<script>
//If user presses number 8 these radios don't have to be required
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('input:radio[name="NeverWornRespbefore"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Yes Never Worn one before') {

            console.log("Number never worn resp triggered");

            $('input[name="eyeIrritation"]').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });

});
```

I had the wrong selector for the radio group.

Comment: `$('input:radio[name="eyeIrritation"]')` or `$('.eyeIrritation')` - could you share your HTML please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set HTML5 required attribute in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18774169/2902660

Comment: Try `$('input[name="eyeIrritation"]').removeAttr('required');`

Comment: @Developer, thank you that worked. I guess i had the Selector wrong.

Comment: You code for `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` simply makes no sense. First the 2nd parameter sets the `value` attribute so its generating `value="Yes"` and `value="No"` respectively, so `new { Value = "YES" }` is pointless. And why in the world are you adding `new { required = "true" }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. Try `$('input[name="eyeIrritation"]').removeAttr('required');`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
.prop('required', false);
```