# Using Angular ng-attr for the disabled attribute

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use [ng-attr](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes) to conditionally add an attribute to an element. My code is something like this:

```
<label for="theID" 
       ng-attr-disabled="{{true || undefined}}"
       class="control-label">
  Some Label
</label>
```

What I get by inspecting the element is this:

```
<label translate="" for="theID" 
       ng-attr-disabled="{{true || undefined}}" 
       class="control-label ng-scope" disabled="disabled">
  Some Label
</label>
```

But expectation is:

```
<label translate="" for="theID" 
       ng-attr-disabled="{{true || undefined}}" 
       class="control-label ng-scope"
       disabled>
  Some Label
</label>
```

am I wrong altogether about how it works?

Thanks

Comment: Try it without the curly quotes (though that's going to just evaluate to true, but whatever).

Comment: Then it looks like this: ng-attr-disabled="true || undefined"

Comment: Yes, but true || undefined will always evaluate to true. So why even bother with ng-attr? Why not just use disabled?

Comment: "true" is just to make a point. There will be a real expression. So, why "disabled" attribute is  getting a value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6961821/3055401

Comment: Probably has to do with the syntax for adding an attribute in jquery, which angular uses under the hood. If you don't use the value parameter, you're reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you should care about it, in your case. When value is falsy, `disabled` is not present. When value is truthy, is present - and it's all about presence in HTML about attributes like this (like `required` on inputs, validation care about presence `required="false"` makes input required). For example, you can style it dependent on attribute presence: [MDN Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Read my comment, please.

Comment: But I need to get it without any value. Is that possible?

Comment: @Mark I think you can only do it with plain DOM operation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18774169/3368498 . You can try `label translate="" for="theID" id="label1" ng-init="$ctrl.addDisabled('label1')"` and inside `addDisabled(id)` you can do `$document.querySelector("#" + id).setAttribute("disabled", "")`

Answer (score 3):

Angular has a special directive for the `disabled` attribute:

```
<label for="theID" 
        ̶n̶g̶-̶a̶t̶t̶r̶-̶d̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶=̶"̶{̶{̶t̶r̶u̶e̶ ̶|̶|̶ ̶u̶n̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶d̶}̶}̶"̶
        ng-disabled="true || undefined"
        class="control-label">
    Some Label
</label>
```

From the Docs:

> #### ngDisabled
>
> - directive in module ng
>
> This directive sets the `disabled` attribute on the element (typically a form control, e.g. `input`, `button`, `select` etc.) if the [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) inside `ngDisabled` evaluates to truthy.
>
> A special directive is necessary because we cannot use interpolation inside the `disabled` attribute. See the [interpolation guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) for more info.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-disabled Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable element in Angular 4+ just add **disabled** attribute with your **condition**

```
<label for="theID" 
 disabled="condition"
 class="control-label">
    Some Label
</label>
```