# required codes in script are not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

the required in the script do not working

```
$("#s_postby").attr('required', false); // put the id of the input field that you whant required
$("#s_postby").attr('required', true); // put the id of the input field that you whant required
```

I make some radio field in my osclass theme on the item post!

```
    <div id="postby" class="property-ads-100">
      <label>
        <span class="required_fields">*</span>
        <?php _e('Posted By', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
      </label>
      <div class="item-post-postby-checkbox columns-0">
        <input  type="radio" name="s_postby" value="owner" id="s_postby0" <?php if(isset($housing['s_postby']) && $housing['s_postby'] =='owner') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }; ?>>
        <label for="s_postby0">
          <?php _e('Owner', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="item-post-postby-checkbox columns-0">
        <input type="radio" name="s_postby" value="agent" id="s_postby1" <?php if(isset($housing['s_postby']) && $housing['s_postby'] =='agent') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }; ?>>
        <label for="s_postby1">
          <?php _e('Agent', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="item-post-postby-checkbox columns-0">
        <input type="radio" name="s_postby" value="broker" id="s_postby2" <?php if(isset($housing['s_postby']) && $housing['s_postby'] =='broker') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }; ?>>
        <label for="s_postby2">
          <?php _e('Broker', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="item-post-postby-checkbox columns-0">
        <input type="radio" name="s_postby" value="agency" id="s_postby3" <?php if(isset($housing['s_postby']) && $housing['s_postby'] =='agency') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }; ?>>
        <label for="s_postby3">
          <?php _e('Agency', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I hide this on some categories (the required in the script do not work!!) Why??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#catId').change(function(){
    if( $('#catId').val() == "28" || $('#catId').val() == "29" || 
$('#catId').val() == "30" || $('#catId').val() == "31")
    {
        $("#postby").hide();  // change Posted By with ID you give to the div
    $("#s_postby").attr('required', false); // put the id of the input field that you whant required
    }else
    {
         $("#postby").show(); // change Posted By with ID you give to the div
    $("#s_postby").attr('required', true); // put the id of the input field that you whant required
    }
});
</script>
```

What i need now it to make this radio fields required when show and not required wen hide! When show and required i need a error message Posted By: This field is required!

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: I don't think `#s_postby` will match `#s_postbyNUMBER`. `$('input[name="postby"]).each` might be closer.. I don't JS much though, PHP brought me here.

Comment: Thanks i will try this and let you know if working

Answer (score 2):

```
element.required = true;
```

[How to set HTML5 required attribute in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: *"Oh, and nobody cares that you are a female student."* - that mention shouldn't have been in the answer and I edited out that fluff and in the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But I am right

Comment: That's a comment that should be best kept to one's self ;-)