# Making additional elements required

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, required

I am creating a form submission; some of the elements are required so are not.  I have a `checkbox` in the form that will make additional elements visible if the box is checked.  I am using [html](/questions/tagged/html)and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

The problem I am currently having is that when I hit submit the elements that are invisible are still required (I will attach my code). I want to make it where the additional elements are required **only** when the box is checked.
I am not sure how to write the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)to make this possible.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

```js
function addPerson(box) {
  var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("person");
  var vis = "none";
  for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
    if (chboxs[i].checked) {
      vis = "block";
      break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;
}
```

```html
<html>
<form>
  *Name: <input size=27 type="text" name="mfname" required><br> *Email: <input size=27 type="text" name="mfname" required><br> *Date: <input size=27 type="text" name="mfname" required><br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="person" value="on" onclick="addPerson('person')">Add another person<br>

  <div id="person" style="display:none">
    *Name: <input size=27 type="text" name="mfname" required><br> *Email: <input size=27 type="text" name="mfname" required><br> *Date: <input size=27 type="text" name="mfname" required><br>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

For each element (or children) you're hiding you can do

```
yourElement.removeAttribute('required');
```

and when showing

```
yourElement.setAttribute('required',true);
```