# unable set required attribute to true with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form.When I submit that form the require attribute of the text field of that form should be set to true.I am trying this with javascript.But unable get the positive result.My code is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function validate()
        {
            alert("ok");
            document.getElementById("sample").required = true;//method-1

      document.getElementById("sample").setAttribute("required","")//method-2
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="validate()">
            <input type="text" id="sample">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

in both these methods I am unable to set required to true.any help please...

Comment: In second method why you set blank ?

Comment: I read in stackoverflow that assigning like that is equal to true

Comment: provide the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can return on form submit like below example. This is reference [url](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp).

```
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php"onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

**See Demo**

> With element.required = true;

```js
function validate() {
  var el = document.getElementById("sample");
  if (el.value) {
    alert(el.value);
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Value is required..');
    el.required = true; //method-1
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="sample">
  <input  type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

> With element.setAttribute("required", "");

```js
function validate() {
  var el = document.getElementById("sample");
  if (el.value) {
    alert(el.value);
  } else {
    alert('Value is required..')
    el.setAttribute("required", "");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="sample">
  <input  type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: can't we do this on submit

Comment: @MaththiBasavaKoteswaraRaavu I have updated my answer. Please check.