# How to change RequiredField dynamically?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a dropdownlist and when I selected a value from it I am checking the value from another table and according to returning value I change the visibility of a layout item. Now I need to set it Required if it is visible(If the value from ajax is 3 or 5). How can I do it? Here is my ajax that set visible or not.

Edit: I want to set liGid required when in if condition.

```
`$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "TestPage.aspx/GetCode",
   data: '{"XKod":"' + s.GetValue().toString() + '"}',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (msg) {
      if (msg.d.GrupKodu == 3 || msg.d.GrupKodu == 5) {
         fytbTab0.GetItemByName('liGid').SetVisible(true);
      }
      else {
         fytbTab0.GetItemByName('liGid').SetVisible(false);

      }
   }
});`
```

Comment: [setting the required field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
 fytbTab0.GetItemByName('liGid').required = true;
```

Comment: I am trying to write .required but it doesnt appear in the list.