# Using JS in thymeleaf template for one field depends on another option

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot application using thymeleaf on the frontend. I need to make comment (text area below) field as "required" if some option is selected from the  for a question and if the option is not selected that means option is "please select" then required attribute is not applied to text area. I am using javascript to check this as below.

```
 <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
                <div class="form-group table" th:if="${answeredQuestionnaire.answers.size()==0}">
                    <table>
                        <thead style="background-color: dimgrey; color: white">
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                                <th scope="col" class="col-4 text-center">[[#{questionnaire.question}]]</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="col-4 text-center">[[#{questionnaire.answer}]]</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="col-4 text-center" >[[#{questionnaire.comment}]]<font color="red">*</font></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody th:field="*{questionnaire}">
                            <tr th:each="question,iStat : ${answeredQuestionnaire.questionnaire.getQuestions()}"
                                class="d-flex">
                                <td class="col-4" th:inline="text">
                                    <input type="hidden"  th:value="${question.id}"
                                           th:field="*{questionnaire.questions[__${iStat.index}__].id}"
                                           th:text="${question.questionNumber + 1}+') '+#{'question'+${question.questionNumber}}"/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-4 text-center">
                                    <select th:field="*{questionnaire.questions[__${iStat.index}__].possibleAnswers[0].id}"
                                            class="form-control" onselect="makeCommentRequiredIfOptionSelected2()"/>
                                    <option value="" default id="noSelectOption2" >[[#{pleaseSelect}]]</option>
                                    <option th:each="possibleAnswer, paStat : ${question.getPossibleAnswers()}"
                                            th:value="${possibleAnswer.id}"
                                            th:text="#{'question'+${question.questionNumber}+'.pa'+${paStat.index}}">
                                    </option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-4">
                                    <textarea id="commentAreaForQuestion2" th:value="${question.comment}" placeholder="comment"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              th:field="*{questionnaire.questions[__${iStat.index}__].comment}"
                                              th:placeholder="#{comment}"
                                              rows="3" ></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have js added to this thymeleaf template as :

```
<script th:src="@{/js/actions.js}"> </script>
```

and the js file is :

```
function makeCommentRequiredIfOptionSelected2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("noSelectOption2").value;
    if (x == "") document.getElementById("commentAreaForQuestion2").setAttribute("required", true);
    else document.getElementById("commentAreaForQuestion2").setAttribute("required", false);
}
```

The JS seems to be loaded properly(I check the inspect>sources in the browser). But there is no functionality visible (if I select an option from the dropdown list, still text area field is not set to "required"). I am new to JS so I don't know whats wrong here.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is not working and what you have tried already?

Comment: I wrote some text with explaination. The basic problem is that JS does not seems to be working. The comment field (text area element) is not set with required attribute when I select an option from the dropdown list.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript you should not use `setAttribute()` for required.