# How to choose attribute for a tag with no value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input tag I can change its attributes which takes some value e.g.

```
<input type="text">

<script>
    var inputEls = document.querySelector("input");
    inputEls.placeholder = "Enter Name";
</script>
```

But how I can change put attributes that doesn't take attributes say autofocus.

```
inputEls.autofocus ??
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794394/setting-autofocus-attribute-with-javascript-not-working ?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan it's the same subject matter, but the answers on that question are not very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `autofocus` property is a boolean property, so you set it to `true` or `false`:

```
inputEls.autofocus = true;
```

Not all properties like that are boolean. For example, the `autocomplete` property has a string value, either `"off"` or `"on"`.

You can look up things like this [at the Mozilla Developer Network Wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) or in the sprawling HTML5 spec. (*edit* — I went to look for a good link into the W3C spec, but I can't find `autofocus` documented there.)

Note that setting the `autofocus` flag doesn't seem to do anything in Firefox at least. I've tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input id=x>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("x").autofocus=true;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

in a small test file and it doesn't do anything in Firefox, but it works in Chrome. Similarly, that same test with the "autofocus" attribute in the HTML and the JavaScript setting it to `false` doesn't turn it off either.

In either Chrome or Firefox, setting the flag after the page has fully loaded doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Just put this in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d4g0tbz3/. Not seeing the autofocus on the input. Any reason why?

Comment: @dowomenfart I suspect it's because it's in an `<iframe>` but I don't know for sure.

Comment: OK, forgot about the iframes in jsfiddle. Just tried the code locally and the code works. UP VOTE.

Comment: @dowomenfart really? I can't get it to do anything, but I'll keep trying. *edit* oh it works in Chrome.

Comment: yeah, works for me in chrome version (Version 41.0.2272.76 m) but doesn't work in I.E 11.